# Magento Exchange payment on products module

Tags: magento

I am working on a requirement of following in magento.

Case 1: Customer sell mobile 
- Customer will choose mobile to sell. 
- If there is no purchase of any new mobile, then cart will contain amount site needs to pay to customer. 
- In this order, there will be no payment methods for customer to pay, but we need to provide some interface, so customer can specify his bank details. So site can pay for his/her mobile.

Case 2: Customer want to buy mobile 
- This is same as default magento functionality. 
- In this case, cart will have amount which will be paid by customer to site. (normalmagento order).

Case 3: Customer want to buy mobile and also want to sell old mobile (Swap mobile) 
- In this, cart will have 2 products. 1 for sell and 1 to buy. 
- Cart total will be difference of new mobile cost and old mobile value.

- If old mobile value is greater than new mobile, then customer will get payment from site. And in the same way, if new mobile value is greater than old mobile then customer will pay the difference. If both are same then no payment will be done.

What should be done in order to fulfill this?